# Android Date Time Format Pattern

Tags: android, date, format, jodatime

I want to know if there is a way to get the format that is currently being used by the system.
As of now i am using the Joda Time library and manually specifying the foramt that i expect the date to be in.

```
private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(event_date, formatter);
```

This is of course not the best idea to hardcode the pattern,so is there a way i can get the pattern from the system?

Comment: Check DateUtils http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
String pattern       = ((SimpleDateFormat)formatter).toPattern();
String localPattern  = ((SimpleDateFormat)formatter).toLocalizedPattern();
```

Comment: Tried this way and it returns a pattern of MMMM d, y in my case which does not meet the format the date values are actually stored in.In case you need more details i am trying to scan events from the contacts on the phone and for this i need to supply a date format when scanning.

Comment: It return whatever your default date pattern is, so MMMM d, y is the default pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
String datePattern;
String timePattern;
void loadDateTimePattern(Context context) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
        datePattern = dateFormat.toPattern();
        timePattern = timeFormat.toPattern();
}

DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(timePattern);
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatterFull = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(datePattern + ", " + timePattern);
```

Comment: Returns M/d/y in the case of date format but is not conforming to the pattern that the dates actually are in so it does not work.